# Scanning CA lottery ticket barcode?

Tags: ios, swift, barcode, scanning

Does anyone know what type of barcode CA Lottery tickets use for their ticket code? When I use my BarCodeScanner class with all the different types of objecttypes (interleaved2of5 and itf14, etc.), I'm still not able to read the barcode. [Example of Lottery Ticket barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJdHS.jpg)

Comment: How is “what type of barcode CA Lottery tickets use” a _programming_ question?

Answer (score 1):

It is interleaved 2of5, but appears to be using a different check digit calculation than is standard.  I get a decode of 14211259012022000000000431.